# java- Swing- Weird GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout

This is my code:

```
package darkorbit;

import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class GuiPreparation extends JFrame{

    private JCheckBox cbbt = new JCheckBox("Wait");
    private JTextField tfbt = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel mbt = new JLabel("-");
    private JTextField tfbt1 = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel lbt = new JLabel("miliseconds after collecting a box.");

    private JCheckBox cbr = new JCheckBox("Rest");
    private JTextField tfr = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel mr = new JLabel("-");
    private JTextField tfr1 = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel lr = new JLabel("seconds every");
    private JTextField tfr2 = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel mr1 = new JLabel("-");
    private JTextField tfr3 = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel lr1 = new JLabel("minutes.");

    private JButton startBotting = new JButton("Start Botting");
    private int controlWidth = 500;
    private int controlHeight = 600;

    GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    int screenWidth = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();

    private GuiPreparation(){

        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(screenWidth / 2 - controlWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2 - controlHeight / 2, controlWidth, controlHeight);

        eventStartBotting startBottingEvent = new eventStartBotting();

        startBotting.addActionListener(startBottingEvent);
        //startBotting.setBounds(controlWidth / 2 - 100 / 2, controlHeight - 70, 100, 30);


        //Layout

        add(startBotting);
        add(cbbt);
        add(tfbt);
        add(mbt);
        add(tfbt1);
        add(lbt);

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                        .addComponent(cbbt))
                        .addComponent(tfbt)
                        .addComponent(mbt)
                        .addComponent(tfbt1)
                        .addComponent(lbt)
                );

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                        .addComponent(cbbt)
                        .addComponent(tfbt)
                        .addComponent(mbt)
                        .addComponent(tfbt1)
                        .addComponent(lbt))
                );

        layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, tfbt);
        layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, tfbt1);


        //Layout1

        add(cbr);
        add(tfr);
        add(mr);
        add(tfr1);
        add(lr);
        add(tfr2);
        add(mr1);
        add(tfr3);
        add(lr1);


        GroupLayout layout1 = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout1);

        layout1.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout1.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        layout1.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout1.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout1.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                        .addComponent(cbr))
                        .addComponent(tfr)
                        .addComponent(mr)
                        .addComponent(tfr1)
                        .addComponent(lr)
                        .addComponent(tfr2)
                        .addComponent(mr1)
                        .addComponent(tfr3)
                        .addComponent(lr1)
                );

        layout1.setVerticalGroup(
                layout1.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(50)
                .addGroup(layout1.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                        .addComponent(cbr)
                        .addComponent(tfr)
                        .addComponent(mr)
                        .addComponent(tfr1)
                        .addComponent(lr)
                        .addComponent(tfr2)
                        .addComponent(mr1)
                        .addComponent(tfr3)
                        .addComponent(lr1))
                );

        layout1.linkSize(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, tfr);
        layout1.linkSize(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, tfr1);
        layout1.linkSize(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, tfr2);
        layout1.linkSize(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, tfr3);

    }

    public class eventStartBotting implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent startBottingActionEvent) {
            System.out.println("Event Start Botting");
            startBotting.setEnabled(false);

            GuiBotting.openGui();

            setVisible(false);
            dispose();

        }
    }

    public static void openGui() {
        GuiPreparation mainGUI = new GuiPreparation();
        mainGUI.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

So when I run the gui (`openGui()`), it runs smoothly, i get what i want:
[image: What I want]

But then I change(for example) setReziseable(true) instead of false and run it I get this:
[image: What I don't want]

When I set it back i get the same.

And to get the gui I want again, I have to press Ctrl+z untill it is set back to it's original.

Sometimes I get the weird one even when i havent changed anything

These are examples, y get this weird things by changing anything, and get different results even when the code is exactly the same.

Is it the use of 2 layouts? is it that it doesn't shut down correctly? It if matters, I use Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not get your first picture, regardless of the setting of resizable.

You are adding your components too many times -- after they are added to a GroupLayout layout (once for horizontal and once for vertical), they do not also need to be added to the content pane -- remove all the add() methods that are not doing things with the GroupLayout.

Also, only one layout is connected to your JFrame at a time -- when you set layout1 as the content pane layout, you replace the layout you previously set.  Either put all the components into one layout, or have a JPanel, set to GroupLayout, for each of the two vertical portions, and then put the two JPanels into another JPanel, and then set that one into the center of your JFrame (you could put one north and one center, but then they would stretch differently if you allow the user to change the frame size).